# Database connection fails with Local IIS but works with IIS Express

Tags: entity-framework, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-express

I am working on MVC with Entity Framework. My solution is able to connect to database, SQL Server 2008 R2, when I run my solution with IIS Express, as soon as I change to Local IIS, it starts throwing error: `An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code.`

While Error Message was: `The underlying provider failed on Open.`

I am able to browse through pages which do not require database connection.

Following is the web.config file

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>

<section name="entityFramework"    type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
 </configSections>

<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>

<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

  <dependentAssembly>

    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>

    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />

  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

<system.codedom>
 <compilers>

  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />

  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>

</system.codedom>

<entityFramework>

 <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>

   <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>

</entityFramework>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="server=.; Database=Database1; integrated security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: i would like to see your web config file